# Angular 2 issue setting value inside subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular

I am doing a post on server and trying to console output the response http code. I used chrome tool as debugger to check response and I can see the output coming but at the end it goes to subscribe library does something and sets the function rather than value.

> My component class is

```
 export class MicroserviceCreateComponent implements OnInit{

   errorMessage: string;
   postMessage: string;
   teams: Team[];
   microservice: Microservice[];

    constructor(private microserviceService: MicroserviceService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: Microservice, valid: boolean }) {
     this.createMicroservice(value); 
     console.log(this.postMessage); <<<<<<<<==== This gives me undefined
  }

   createMicroservice(value){
      this.microserviceService.createMicroservice(value).subscribe(
        postMessage => this.postMessage = postMessage.valueOf(),
         error => {
          this.errorMessage = error.getMessage();
          console.error(error.getDescription());
        });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `console.log(this.postMessage);`?

Comment: @echonax Sorry that was stupid. I edited that. Now its giving undefined.

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2 ?

Comment: @echonax Yeah thats awsome. Thanks

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: @echonax Yes its clear now what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Alright then, I'm flagging it as a dupe to chain the questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

`this.microserviceService.createMicroservice(value).subscribe( . . . )` is a non-blocking asynchronous call. Meaning that after you call it `console.log(this.postMessage)` is free to print before the web request is complete. Try putting the `console.log(this.postMessage)` in the subscription.

```
this.createMicroservice(value); // This is an async call
console.log(this.postMessage); // This happens immediately afterwards
```

Comment: Have you read the comments?

Comment: I started typing the answer before they were posted >.<

Comment: Ah ok, I see :-)

Comment: It is obnoxious that Stack Overflow doesn't do a better job notifying you that the post has changed before posting.